# Redirect callback is not called but redirect URI is visited

Tags: reactjs, azure, redirect, callback, azure-ad-msal

I try to login with Microsoft Azure.

What works so far:

- When using `loginPopup().then(response => console.log(response)` I am asked to login and then get the token, which I print here. That means to me, that everything is set up and cofigured properly.
- The user experience is not to bother the user with popups but to use `loginRedirect()` instead. I am asked again to login and afterwards I'm redirected to the registered URI (AuthPage).

The catch:

- The registered callback function is never called. I want to store the received token in the App and setup different routes when the user is logged in. Why is the callback not called?
- If I don't use `msalObj.handleRedirectCallback(callback);` I get an error. Aparently some callback function must be set.
- Why do I need the callback if I get redirected to the *redirectURI* anyway and can extract the token from the URL?

Sources I found most helpful:

- [Official Microsoft Msal Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-sign-in?tabs=javascript)

---

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Configuration, UserAgentApplication } from "msal";


export const LoginPage = (props) => {
  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    const msalConfig = {
      auth: {
        clientId: `${process.env.REACT_APP_AAD_CLIENT_ID}`,
        authority: `${process.env.REACT_APP_AAD_AUTHORITY}/${process.env.REACT_APP_AAD_TENANT_ID}`,
        redirectUri: `${process.env.REACT_APP_AAD_REDIRECT_URI}`,
      },
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: "localStorage",
        storeAuthStateInCookie: true
      }
    };
    const requestObj = {
      scopes: ["user.read"]
    };

    const callback = (error, response) => {
      console.log(response);
      props.onRedirect(error, response);
    };

    e.preventDefault();
    const msalObj = new UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);
    msalObj.handleRedirectCallback(callback);
    msalObj.loginRedirect(requestObj);
  };

  return (
    <>
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <hr />
    <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <button type="submit">Login with Azure</button>
    </form>
    </>
  );
};
```